# Disable Spring configuration by a property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a library that should support connections to Aerospike or MariaDb, depending on the properties. It has two appropriate configs:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "aerospike", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class AerospikeConfiguration {
```

and

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "mariadb", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class MariadbConfiguration {
```

and the main config, including both of them

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Import({
        AerospikeConfiguration.class, MariadbConfiguration.class, // and other
})
public class MainAutoConfiguration {
```

Aerospike separately works well, but when I include Maria with all its dependencies, it fails because of the absent `dataSource` bean.

The fastest fix is to add empty properties like `spring.datasource.url`, but I don't want to do it this way.

Other options found here didn't help me:

1. Add `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})` to AerospikeConfiguration leads to the circular @Import error with MainAutoConfiguration.
2. Add `exclude`  to @ SpringBootApplication - I can't do this because the application will be called on clients of my library (and I shouldn't bother them with adding some magic from the start).

Is there a way to change my configs to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use Datasource routing. You can follow this Baeldung article : [AbstractRoutingDatasource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source)

With this you could setup your datasource depdending the properties enabled.

Comment: In general, their approach means adding this for me in the AerospikeConfiguration:
```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().url("jdbc:mariadb://fake").build();
}
```
because Aerospike doesn't need dataSource at all. Looks like a hack, but I still can't do it better.